# How to check if image contains text or not?

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, python-tesseract

Given any image of a scanned document, I want to check if it's not empty page.
I know I can send it to AWS Textract - but it will cost money for nothing.

I know I can use pytesseract but maybe there is more elegant and simple solution?
Or given a .html file that represents the text of the image - how to check it shows a blank page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyMuPDF would be another option for you if you need to save the hassles without going through Pytesseract. Here is just an example of how you could extract text from scanned image or clean format of PDFs:

```
import fitz

input_file = 'path/to/your/file'
pdf_file = input_file
doc = fitz.open(pdf_file) # open pdf files using fitz bindings 
noOfPages = doc.pageCount # Here is how you get number of pages 

for pageNo in range(noOfPages):
    page = doc.loadPage(pageNo) # number of pages
    blocks = page.getText("blocks")
    blocks.sort(key=lambda block: block[3])  # sort by 'y1' values

    for block in blocks:
        print(block[4])  # print the lines of this block or do your check here
```

`page.getText(option)` is probably your best bet and `option` is a string which controls the output type. You can choose among things like plain text, single words with position info, HTML or XML string output, complete page content in Python dict format and what not.

**EDIT:**

A quick way to work with jpg is to convert it back to pdf using:

```
pdfbytes = doc.convertToPDF()
pdf = fitz.open('pdf',pdfbytes)
```

If you don't want to convert it back to pdf, then use `page.getText` with the "dict" parameter. This creates a list of all images on a page:

```
d = page.getText("dict")
blocks = d["blocks"]
imgblocks = [b for b in blocks if b["type"] == 1]
```

If both of them don't satisfy your need, then `PIL` library might be your next option. If you need extra information, here is [official documentation for PyMuPDF](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/) and [here](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/textpage/#textpage) since you mentioned HTML on other threads.

Comment: What is noOfPages and where do I take it from?
@liamsuma

Comment: And I deal with jpg only, given a jpg image - I want to check if the jpg isn't blank.

Comment: @SteveS I will edit it accordingly. give me some time

Comment: @liamsuma apologies for the semi-unrelated question, inside the fitz package, is there a way to extract field form coordinates? example is an editable pdf with boxes you can type in, I am trying to extract the coordinates of those boxes from a blank form pdf...

Comment: @El_1988 no worries and thanks for introducing a new topic for me to study. I think what you are referring to is related to widget if I understand it correctly. please see this link: (https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/widget.html)

Answer (score 1):

We can use pytesseract for this application by *thresholding* the image and passing it to tesseract. However if you have a .html file that represents text of image, you can use *beautifulsoup* for extracting text from it and check if it is empty.Still this is a round way approach.

Comment: Please add code how to to extract text from .html file?