# how to classify if images contain text or not?

Tags: python, image, classification, ocr

I have a lot of images extracted from Search engine, and I am use OCR to perform descent text extraction from these image, but There are images that do not contain text.

Thus I would like to determine if an image simply contains text or not in python, and if it doesn't, i wouldn't have to perform OCR on it. Ideally this method would have a high recall.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if image contains text or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62580362/how-to-check-if-image-contains-text-or-not)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pytteseract. Something like this:

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

def contains_text(image_path):
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(image_path))
    
    if text == "":
        return False # No text detected
    else:
        return text
```

I do not know of a way to detect that there is no text without trying to perform OCR (like above).

Comment: I tried this way, but an error occurred                                                                                          ( UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file ) in line "Image.open(image_path)"

Comment: Were you using the absolute path to the image or the relative path? Sometimes using the relative path can cause problems. If you want to use the relative path you need to add (at the top) something like this: `import os` and change text to: `text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(Image.open(os.getcwd()+image_path)))`